# flutter hover-like touch handling - detect touch from different widgets without lifting the finger

Tags: flutter, mobile, hover, touch-event

Assume I have 3 `Container`s on the screen that react touching by changing their color. When user's finger is on them, they should change color and when touching ends they should turn back to normal. **What I want is that those containers to react when the user finger/pointer on them even if the touch started on a random area on the screen, outside of the containers.** So basically what i am looking for is something just like css hover.

If i wrap each container with `GestureDetector` seperately, they will not react to touch events which start outside of them. On another question (unfortunately i dont have the link now) it is suggested to wrap all the containers with one `GestureDetector` and assign a `GlobalKey` to each to differ them from each other.

Here is the *board* that detects touch gestures:

```dart
class MyBoard extends StatefulWidget {
  static final keys = List<GlobalKey>.generate(3, (ndx) => GlobalKey());

  ...
}

class _MyBoardState extends State<MyBoard> {
  ...

  /// I control the number of buttons by the number of keys,
  /// since all the buttons should have a key
  List<Widget> makeButtons() {
    return MyBoard.keys.map((key) {
      // preapre some funcitonality here
      var someFunctionality;
      return MyButton(key, someFunctionality);
    }).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: (tapDownDetails) {
        handleTouch(context, tapDownDetails.globalPosition);
      },
      onTapUp: (tapUpDetails) {
        finishTouch(context);
      },
      onPanUpdate: (dragUpdateDetails) {
        handleTouch(context, dragUpdateDetails.globalPosition);
      },
      onPanEnd: (panEndDetails) {
        finishTouch(context);
      },
      onPanCancel: () {
        finishTouch(context);
      },
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        width: 300.0,
        height: 600.0,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: makeButtons(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here is the simple `MyButton`:

```dart
class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey key;
  final Function someFunctionality;
  MyButton(this.key, this.someFunctionality) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<KeyState>(
      builder: (buildContext, keyState, child) {
        return Container(
          width: 100.0,
          height: 40.0,
          color: keyState.touchedKey == this.key ? Colors.red : Colors.white,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

In the `_MyBoardState` that's how i handle detecting which `MyButton` is touched:

```dart
MyButton getTouchingButton(Offset globalPosition) {
    MyButton currentButton;
    // result is outside of [isTouchingMyButtonKey] for performance
    final result = BoxHitTestResult();

    bool isTouchingButtonKey(GlobalKey key) {
      RenderBox renderBox = key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
      Offset offset = renderBox.globalToLocal(globalPosition);
      return renderBox.hitTest(result, position: offset);
    }

    var key = MyBoard.keys.firstWhere(isTouchingButtonKey, orElse: () => null);
    if (key != null) currentButton = key.currentWidget;

    return currentButton;
  }
```

I am using provider package and instead of rebuilding the whole `MyBoard` with `setState` only the related part of related `MyButton` will be rebuilded. Still each button has a listener which rebuilds at every update and I am using `GlobalKey`. [On the flutter docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html) it says:

> Global keys are relatively expensive. If you don't need any of the features listed above, consider using a Key, ValueKey, ObjectKey, or UniqueKey instead.

However if we look at `getTouchingButton` method I need `GlobalKey` to get `renderBox` object and to get `currentWidget`. I also have to make a hitTest for each `GlobalKey`. This computation repeats when the `onPanUpdate` is triggered, which means when the user's finger moves a pixel.

UI is not updating fast enough. With a single tap (tapDown and tapUp in regular speed) you usually do not see any change on the `MyButton`s.

If I need to sum up my question, **How can i detect same single touch (no lifting) from different widgets when finger is hoverin on them in more efficient and elegant way?**

Comment: Hi Letitbe, I'm looking to implement something similar (still a little amazed Flutter doesn't have a simple hittest solution for when a finger passes within a widgets bounds) - do you have a working snippet on github at all?

Comment: I've created a repo here https://github.com/FickleLife/flutter_touch_hittest_demo, it's compiling but not working, so I'm obviously missing things...

Comment: @user1048175 unfortunately i don't have a repo as example. Took the code from question and update it as described in the answer. Shortly; before, i had kept the buttons simple, made them stateless widgets and passed the onTouch function (not the name of the function in code snippets) while creating each widget. But as solution i have wrote stateful widget, kept the state **public** and implemented most of the touch functionality hardcoded in the state. Notice that I still pass a GlobalKey to each button, find their states by those keys and call method of the state (that's why they are public).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since no one answered yet, I am sharing my own solution which I figured out lately. Now I can see the visual reaction everytime i touch. It is fast enough, but still it feels like there is a little delay on the UI and it feels a little hacky instead of a concrete solution. If someone can give better solution, I can mark it as *accepted answer*.

---

**My solution:**

First things first; since we have to detect Pan gesture and we are using `onPanUpdate` and `onPanEnd`, I can erase `onTapDown` and `onTapUp` and instead just use `onPanStart`. This can also detect non-moving simple tap touches.

I also do not use `Provider` and `Consumer` anymore, since it rebuilds all the `Consumer`s at every update. This is really a big problem when the the number of `MyButton`s increase. Instead of keeping `MyButton` simple and dummy, I moved touch handling work into it. Each `MyButton` hold the data of *if they are touched at the moment*.

Updated button is something like this:

```dart
class NewButton extends StatefulWidget {
  NewButton(Key key) : super(key: key);
  @override
  NewButtonState createState() => NewButtonState();
}

class NewButtonState extends State<NewButton> {
  bool isCurrentlyTouching = false;

  void handleTouch(bool isTouching) {
    setState(() {
      isCurrentlyTouching = isTouching;
    });
    // some other functionality on touch
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 100.0,
      height: 40.0,
      color: isTouched ? Colors.red : Colors.white,
    );
  }
}
```

**Notice** that `NewButtonState` is not private. We will be using `globalKey.currentState.handleTouch(bool)` where we detect the touch gesture.

Comment: I'm struggling with something similar. I came across this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50639652/how-to-swipe-drag-2-or-more-buttons-in-a-grid-of-buttons-using-flutter/52625182 Rémi Rousselet's answer might work in this case too.