# Flutter Creating Interactable Maps

Tags: flutter

I just started to learn Flutter. I'm trying to create an interactable map. I created it with "[Countries World Map](https://pub.dev/packages/countries_world_map)" package. This is a web project and I want to appear some tip panels when user hovers on countries or cities. But this package uses gesture detector to detect inputs and gesture detector has no hover event. I tried to edit package files but I could only add some new gesture detector events (drags etc.) as a beginner. How can I do this?

https://examples.simplewidgets.dev/#/countries_world_map

Here you can see example of package. As you can see, there is only click event.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a hover event, I guess you're doing flutter web instead of mobile? It looks like there's a MouseRegion widget you might want to use instead? This post might help: [How do I detect if a GestureDetector is hovered in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65025809/how-do-i-detect-if-a-gesturedetector-is-hovered-in-flutter)

Comment: Yes it's a web app like I wrote. I already read this subjects but the problem is I can't implement this widgets to this package. It's not suitable I think.

Comment: Can you clarify why you can't implement it/think it's not suitable?

Comment: Ah, looking through the documentation and that library only provides an onTapUp callback. In that case your options are to find an alternative library, get very creative, or update this one. Since you're just learning, I'd first try to find a different library, but if you can't you could consider drawing this map in a stack widget, with an invisible mouse region in the same place. You'd probably have to manually track pixel positions vs map areas though, so I don't imagine that would be fun.